# How to make a new line in a txt file when taking in data from a text file?

Tags: php, html, line, submit, newline

I'm trying to make the smallest possible chat I can in php and html. I have it set so any data sent from a input text box is sent to a file named data.txt. I then have `iframed` the data.txt like `<iframe src="data.txt"></iframe>` and to make it more viewable I have css

```
div, iframe {  
    width: 100%;  
    height: 100px;   
    margin: 0 auto; 
    background-color: #777;
}
```

Basically, the point is i would like it so each time the form is submitted and text is written into `data.txt` I would like for a new line to be made. I use this php:

```
if(isset($_POST['textdata1']))
{
$data=$_POST['textdata1'];
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
}
```

I tried to put a \n in a couple different spots but i just kept getting errors. Anyway, I know this was kind of long and it didn't have to be but I wanted to make sure you had all information needed. **Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to put `. "\n"` in `fwrite($fp, $data);` but unfortunately after i asked a question on repl.it forums my school blocked repl.it so i can no longer code online. (I use my chromebook to code.)